# How to get penetration vector of two rects?

Tags: geometry, collision, rectangles

Suppose if I have two rects with x,y,w,h and one is stationary and the other is moving at vx, vy. I already calculated that they overlap each other and I know the overlap rect as well. What I am interested in finding out is the red vector in the below graph:

[image]

This is different than a minimum adjustment vector because as you can see, the minimum adjustment would just move rect A leftwards, whereas the red vector moves it leftwards and upwards. Is there an efficient way to calculate this?

Comment: Is needed vector just R.TopLeft-R.BottomRight, where R is overlap rect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The movement vector `V0` and penetration vector `V1` are anti-parallel**

so you can exploit that:
[image: img]
where `dx,dy` is the overlap area size so

```
if (|V0.x|>=|V0.y|)
 {
 V1.x=-sign(V0.x)*|dx|
 V1.y=-sign(V0.y)*|dx*V0.y/V0.x|
 }

if (|V0.x|<|V0.y|)
 {
 V1.y=-sign(V0.y)*|dy|
 V1.x=-sign(V0.x)*|dy*V0.x/V0.y|
 }
```

Hope I did not make some silly mistake but anyway the idea behind should be strait-forward. If not make the parametric line equation of `V0` ... You can also exploit the `dot` product for this but that should lead to the same results ...